# NameError: name 'getResultFromDatabase' is not defined

Tags: python

I'm getting this error:

```
NameError: name 'getResultFromDatabase' is not defined
```

Here is my code:

```
import pymongo

from itertools import groupby
from pymongo import Connection

data = getResultFromDatabase()
connection = Connection('localhost', 27017)

db = connection.students

item = db.grades.find({'type' : 'homework'}).sort([('student_id',pymongo.ASCENDING),('score',pymongo.ASCENDING)])



for id, items in groupby(data, lambda s: s['student_id']):
    lowest_score = min(i['score'] for i in items)

    print lowest_score
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you haven't defined `getResultsFromDatabase`. It either needs to be created or imported from somewhere.

Comment: In particular, if this function is in the pymongo module, then to access it you need to either do `from pymongo import gRFD` then you can use it as in your program; or, if you only do `import pymongo`, then you would use the function as `data = pymongo.gRFD()`. All the functions in a module are attributes of the module, unless they are imported directly as in "from module import specific-function".

Answer (score 0):

A NameError almost always has to do with a mistyped, or not yet imported definition of something, and in your case it is the latter. For any unkown errors you might encounter in the future, it  helps to ctrl-f the [python exceptions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html) page, or whatever library your using page.